# Local build error with turtle-cli, expo-cli No "iOS App Store" profiles for team ... matching

Tags: expo

I’ve been struggling with this error last few days, I use an old mac book pro from late 2012 to create a local IPA file whit the turtle-cli v0.27.4, expo-cli v5.5.1, but this week I notice that my certificate was expired, so I created a new one on the apple developer site. Then I updated the profile with the currently active certificate, I download both of them, and after installing the certificate on my device and export a new .p12 valid Keystore I’m getting an error that says:

“error: exportArchive: No “iOS App Store” profiles for team ‘team_Id_###’ matching ‘certificate_serial_####’ are installed.”

*Could it be that my Xcode can not be updated from v11.3.1?
*What I’m missing, any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after several days, I found the answer, by mistake I execute turtle or turtl-cli command with sudo, and for some reason that I don´t understand yet. by doing this you get the error No "iOS App Store" profiles for team ... matching ... are installed. So I followed the advice in these links

[https://github.com/expo/turtle/issues/247],

[https://github.com/expo/turtle/issues/111].

Those basically suggests that you should change the owner of the following directories:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /private/tpm/xdl
sudo chown -R `whoami` /private/tpm/turtle
sudo chown -R `whoami` /Users/`whoami`/.turtle/workingdir/ios/sdk44
```

Additionally, I'm using nvm so to avoid more issues I chose to install a fresh npm version with his respective copy of turtle-cli, expo-cli without sudo.

I don´t think that has anything to do with it, but I updated my old mac book pro using opencore legacy patcher. To Mac Os Ventura so I can get a newer Xcode version, but even after the update I was getting the same error until I realized that the real problem has to do with permission settings